# Odesk get authenticated user earnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, odesk

Have anybody example of getting earnings information
of odesk authenticated user, in Rails ? How to implement this?
I use odesk-api gem

Answer (score 0):

All necessary data I retrieved via this

```
client = get_client(token, secret) #already authenticated client
profile_url = auth.get_user_info['profile_url']
profile_key = profile_url.split('/').last
p "profile_key found: #{profile_key}"
freelancers = Odesk::Api::Routers::Freelancers::Profile.new(client)
specific_data = freelancers.get_specific(profile_key)
```